# Embed RTMP live streaming link to browser

Tags: flash, rtmp, live-streaming

Anyone knows how to embed rtmp link to be viewed in a browser? I already tried Moeya but it is still not running. Anyone knows other solution to how can I embed this to a browser? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

below is a sample code, hope it helps.

```
<embed width="768" height="456" src="http://www.focusonthefamily.com/family/JWPlayer/mediaplayer.swf" flashvars="allowfullscreen=true&allowscriptaccess=always&autostart=true&shownavigation=true&enablejs=true&volume=50&file=20100809-wait-no-more-v1.mp4&streamer=rtmp://fotffvs.cdnetworks.net/fotffvs/flashstream/fotf/mp4/sohl/2010/&image=http://localhost/~/media/images/advertising_graphics/external_link_odyssey.ashx" />
```

Comment: Full screen mode is not working !!! Player does not switch to full mode. Any help ??