# How to stream RTMPT in a webpage

Tags: html, video-streaming, flash

How can I play the link below within an html file?

```
rtmpt://s4bfl.castup.net/993860018-123.flv?ct=IL&rg=KZ&aid=386&tkn=20130417204452&ts=0&cu=C78D7065-B213-4905-A7E9-73E7994A4443
```

I know I need an SWF player, but I can't find one that works with this link.

For example, this site lets me stream it in the demo
http://www.ideaweb.it/eng/player.cfm.
but I can't find a way to include it in my website.

Comment: you may find this helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497397/embed-rtmp-live-streaming-link-to-browser

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by make an embed of this player http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/ you just need to download the player and upload it to your website and thats it.